# Use MySQL aggregate functions for comparison

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Ok, in a MySQL database I have this `table`:

```
id | value
 1 | 141
 1 | 142
 1 | 143
 2 | 144
 2 | 145
 2 | 148
```

I want to group the table by the `id` and show the number of rows where the `value` is lower than the minimum `value` plus 3.

Expected output for the table above would be:

```
id | counted
 1 | 3
 2 | 2
```

I tried these queries but none of them works:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) counted FROM table WHERE value < MIN(value)+3 GROUP BY id

SELECT id, COUNT(*) counted FROM table GROUP BY id HAVING value < MIN(value)+3

SELECT id, SUM(CASE WHEN value < MIN(value)+3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) counted FROM table GROUP BY id
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match your problem description. min(value)+3 is 144. The rows with value < 144 are the first 3 rows. The output should be 1 row containing id=1 & counted=3

Comment: But... because i group by the id, the minimum value can be different for every id. It's not the minimum value overall that matters, it's just the minimum value of a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table.id id, 
       COUNT(*) counted
FROM   table 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, 
                         MIN(value) m 
                  FROM   table 
                  GROUP  BY id) tmp 
              ON table.id = tmp.id 
WHERE  table.value < tmp.m + 3 
GROUP  BY table.id;
```

The idea is to left join the minimum value for each id, then compare the two rows (value vs. min-value). The temporary table that results from the join looks like this:

```
  table.   |    tmp.
id | value | id  |  m 
-----------------------
 1 |  141  |  1  |  141
 1 |  142  |  1  |  141
 1 |  143  |  1  |  141
 2 |  144  |  2  |  144
 2 |  145  |  2  |  144
 2 |  148  |  2  |  144
```

the output of the above query is:

```
id | counted
 1 | 3
 2 | 2
```